# How to hide views in ios at runtime with auto layouts such that the ui stays consistent?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-ui-automation, ios-autolayout

I am attaching the image of my ui here.

User Inteface:

[image]

I want to make the buttons with grievance details and mdm details captions hidden at runtime depending on the condition but I want the button with logout caption to shift upwards automatically. But its not happening. I am attaching the image of my result.

UI after removing the two buttons:

[image]

And here is the image of the constraints applied on the button with the caption logout.

Constraints applied on the logout button:

[image]

Comment: Try to change the top constraint of logout button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app's Deployment Target is above iOS 9 then you should use UIStackView. You can easily achieve with UIStackView.

[Check this](https://medium.com/@nrewik/easy-animation-with-uistackview-8878b2856ae2#.ykehjmwbi)

Comment: I tried to use stacks and used the auto layout constraints on the stacks but they are giving the same result

Answer (score 1):

Use [UIStackViews](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview). Hidden subviews of stack views are ignored by autolayout.

Also it will be much simpler to use.